# How to send part of the object as argument in ES6

Tags: javascript

I have an axios function.

```
const getData = (id) => {
    let q_type = `
    query getAllData {
        org(id: ${id}) {
            .....        }
    }`;

    finalData(q_type, 'data').then((res) => res);
}

const finalData = async (query_name, restObj) => {
    const result = await axios.post(
        process.env.ENDPOINT,
        { headers: headers },
        { query: qs.parse(query_name) })
        try {
            console.log(result.data[restObj]);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
};
```

The code I have above works fine. But I want to be able to send multiple layers of the object.

What if I want to send `result.data[restObj][nextValue]` and so on. How do I do that?

Comment: Why are you passing that to `finalData`? Just do it when you get the data - `finalData(q_type).then((data) => data.data[nextValue])`, or `finalData(q_type).then(({ data: { [nextValue]: result } }) => result)`. The caller already has to know the structure of the response, so it's not much of an abstraction anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am calling `finalData` inside of `getData`. Its just that, at different times I want different parts of the object.